# What does `a > b` mean?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm reading a tutorial about creating a shoutbox with jquery, php and ajax. In the jquery code, it creates a variable like this

```
var messageList = $(".content > ul");
```

There is a "content" class in the html, and it has an unordered list in it.  But I don't understand the syntax   `.content  > ul` in the creation of the variable.

Can you explain?

**HTML**

```
 <div class="content">  
            <h1>Latest Messages</h1>  
            <div id="loading"><img src="css/images/loading.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>  
            <ul>  
            <ul>  
        </div>
```

Comment: Have a look at http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors and http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It searches for a `ul` that's the **direct** child of `.content`, so if you'd change the html to

```
<div class="content">
   <div>
      <ul></ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

your selector wouldn't return anything. There's more info on all kinds of selectors on http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 2):

It indicates the shoutbox should be applied to a "ul" thats the **immediate** child of ".content". Without the ">" symbol, it applies to **any** ul thats a child of .content

Answer (score 1):

It's a [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/).

Comment: Yes. See the whole list of jQuery selectors here http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

css [child selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors)

Comment: The child selector doesn't work in CSS in IE6, but it does in jQuery, even in IE6.