# using > in jquery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does `a > b` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640751/what-does-a-b-mean)

Hi could any one tel me what this style of selector is used for?

```
$("> div", "#main-content")
```

is it the same as

```
 $("div", "#main-content")
```

?

Not seen this style before and just stumbled on it in a template I just bought.

Comment: Please read the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Comment: > is for direct children only. So if you say 'div > .myclass' it will only get the .myclass that is inside the div and not inside anything else. If a .myclass is inside a span inside that div, it will not be selected. Hope this is clear :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some great answers above.  To specifically answer your question:

How the jQuery structure works:
`$("tagToSelect", "context")`
which can also be expressed as
`$("context tagToSelect")`

The ">" selects only tags immediately inside the context (one level deep)

So 
`$("> div", "#main-content")`
is technically the same as
`$("#main-content > div")`
and will select all divs that are one level into #main-content (but no deeper)

Your other example:
`$("div", "#main-content")`
is technically the same as
`$("#main-content div")`
and will iterate through the entire DOM structure inside #main-content and find all divs

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 4):

Basically the `>` indicates, that only direct children are matched. If the `>` is omitted, then ever child of every level below is matched.

If you have a structure like this:

```
<div id="A">
  <div id="B">
    <div id="C"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

a selector like:

```
#A > #B
```

Should return you B, but

```
#A > #C
```

would not match with C whereas

```
#A #C
```

would.

Answer (score 3):

Just refer to http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/ to clear you doubt about `>`

Answer (score 2):

I think `$("div", "#main-content")` will select ALL the divs in the `#main-content` element's  tree, while the `$("> div", "#main-content")` selects only direct children. For more info see [docs](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/).

Answer (score 2):

parent **>** child - selects only direct child elements
Just to re-iterate:

> Note: The $("> elem", context) selector will be deprecated in a future
>   release. Its usage is thus discouraged in lieu of using alternative
>   selectors.

Answer (score 1):

`>` is used for direct children.

```
<ul id="mainUl">
   <li>
      <ul id="secondaryUl">
         <li></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Here, both `<ul>` tags will be caught with `$("ul")`, but only `#mainUl` will be caught with `$("> ul")`